# Show a loading icon until the page loads its first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a mobile site and for it I was looking to add a loading icon when user clicks on a link. I found a decent tutorial on it - [Check it here](http://bradsknutson.com/blog/display-loading-image-while-page-loads/)

I used this but I am having a problem. It will show loading icon until the page loads fully. But for slower connections it may be long time. What I need is to do that it stops showing loading icon when the page loads it's first content or at least something to show so that user does not need to wait for long time and he can start checking the page while it has been loaded partially. I have no idea how do I do that. Any help would be appreciated. 
This is the code I am using -

```
       <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
    })
    </script>
<div class="loader"></div>

.loader {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url('images/page-loader.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);
}
```

Comment: show some relevant code in the question!

Comment: @Mikelis Baltruks : not duplicate, but good information

Comment: @MikelisBaltruks My question is different. I need that when a user clicks on link it shows loading icon but if it has paged partial content then it should stop that loading icon

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", ready, false );
function ready(){
alert("page initialised");
}
```

Use DOMContentLoaded instead of onload...